# For loop:I don't undestand how the answer for this loop is 170 instead of 120

Tags: java

I saw this code online and was trying to figure out why data1=170 instead of 130.

```
int data1 = 100;
int i;
data1 = data1+10;
for (i = 0; i<3 ; i++) {
    data1=data1+20; // I don't understand how the answer for this loop is 170 instead of 130

}
```

Comment: `100 + 10 + 20 * 3 = 170`.

Comment: What makes you think it should be 120 (or 130 according to the comment in your code)?

Comment: `i = 0; i<3 ; i++` - means that for-loop is executed until `i < 3`. `i` starts from `0`. So, for-loop executes 3 times(`0, 1, 2`)

Comment: before the loop starts, data1 = 110. then in the loop you add 3 times 20 to 110 which is = to 170

Comment: The for-loop runs as long as i < 3, so it runs three times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data1=110

Iteration 1 (i=0, 0<3):
    data1=110+20=130; i++;
Iteration 2 (i=1, 1<3):
    data1=130+20=150; i++;
Iteration 3 (i=2, 2<3):
    data1=150+20=170; i++;
Iteration 4 (i=3, 3<3 is false):
    loop exits.

data1=170.
```

Answer (score 0):

'data1'  before entering the loop is 110(100+10), and the loop runs 3 times, 20 is added in each iteration, so 110+20+20+20 = 170